# Null reference handling for WMI queries

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to query everything in a given WMI class, however I'm getting a null reference returned to me every time I tune my tests.. I'd ideally like to make the query string to be `select * from Win32_BIOS` but I'm trying to sort this error out first. The error occurs when trying to `Console.WriteLine(property)`

```
public class PropertyValue
{
    public PropertyValue()
    {
    }

    public PropertyValue(string wmiClassName)
    {
        WmiClassName = wmiClassName;
    }

    public string WmiClassName { get; set; }


    public void TestString<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
            (String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", propertyName, WmiClassName));

        var collection = moSearcher.Get();
        var enu = collection.GetEnumerator();

        {
            foreach (ManagementBaseObject prop in collection)
            {
                Type t = prop.Properties[propertyName].GetType();
                t.GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(prop, null);
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Properties[propertyName].Value);
            }
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class TestStrings
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestThis()
        {
            PropertyValue propval = new PropertyValue("Win32_BIOS");
            propval.TestString<string>("Manufacturer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically you would debug your unit-test and figure out what line is throwing the exception.  Are you unable to debug your unit test?

Comment: Where is the code throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that this particular machine was returning a null value in WMI.